# error: A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load

Tags: node.js, sails.js

after npm install , getting error like, i have checked every config file and also installed lodash manually after but still not working

```
error: A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load!
error: Error: In Sails v1.x, `sails.config.globals._` must be either `false` or an object (typically the value of `require('lodash')`)
    at Sails.exposeGlobals (D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\exposeGlobals.js:47:44)
    at Sails.wrapper [as exposeGlobals] (D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3250:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Sails.emitter.emit (D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\after.js:50:11)
    at D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\loadHooks.js:111:15
    at Hook.initialize (D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\index.js:154:14)
    at Hook.wrapper [as initialize] (D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3250:19)
    at D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\index.js:88:16
    at D:\Node_Project\POS\trunk\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:486:20
```

Comment: I think it may be related with new version of Sails (now it's 1.x). But upgrade notes from 0.12.x to 1.x are still missing. Try to install sails 0.12.x.

Comment: it was version problem, sails 0.10.5 with newer version of npm due to directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

First :  Make sure you've installed dependencies with **npm install**
Second :  Check that this app was built for a compatible version of **Sails**.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in `config/globals.js`

```
module.exports.globals = {
  moment: true,
  models: false,
  sails: true,
  async: require('async'),
  _: require('lodash'),
};
```

Comment: Please upvote the main issue or any answer if you find it useful and avoid a "thanks" post. About your config, please confirm that the same issue was fixed by the configs; it's even better to clarify what setting helped you fix the problem, or add some explanation about it.